# Can you write a program that alters another program semantically?

Tags: computability

It is definitely possible to write a program that takes another program as an input and changes it *syntactically*, but does not alter the meaning.

But is it possible to write a general program $alter$ that alters the output of a given program $P$ for *some* input, i.e. $\exists x: P(x) \neq alter(P)(x)$? Edit: Let's add the assumption that $\exists k: P(k) \neq \bot$.

---

I was thinking about doing something simple like this:

```
alter(Program P)(x):
   k = findSomeInputWhereHalts(P)
   y = P(k)

   if (x == k) 
     return y+1 // or something else except y
   else 
     return P(x)
```

This requires that $P$ does halt for some input $x$, which is an OK requirement for me. But it seems that there is probably some other counterexample to this specific algorithm or it might be generally uncomputable, but I failed to figure it out.

Edit: How I imagined implementing findSomeInputWhereHalts:

```
findSomeInputWhereHalts(P):
    for each int n:
        for each int k <= n:
            y = run P(k) for n steps
            if (y is defined)
                return k
```

But this obviously never halts if $\nexists k: P(k) \neq \bot$ .

Comment: Try proving your claim. If you succeed, it's true. If you fail, try instead finding a counterexample.

Comment: One question is: will the
function `findSomeInputWhereHalts` return a result when there is one?
what do you think? How does it do it?
Why are you asking that question?

Comment: Why does it "seem" so? Where does that question come from? Do you have reason to believe the answer is yes or no? Hint: `P` may not halt on any `x`. If you restrict yourself to `P` that sometimes halt, your idea (diagonalisation) can work, with some adaptions.

Comment: A conceptual point that underlies your question: formal semantics can deal with characteristics of languages insofar as these characteristics have a syntactical expression. Also: try to explain why your problem is not just a restatement of the halting problem.

Comment: @Raphael: "If you restrict yourself to P that sometimes halt, your idea (diagonalisation) can work, with some adaptions". As I noted, that restriction is okay. But where would I need adaptions?

Comment: @Skrjiban Ah, my mistake. Your program works as is, if it is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: If $P(x)$ doesn't terminate, what does the statement $\exists x: P(x) \neq alter(P)(x)$ mean? What should $alter(P)$ do if $P$ doesn't terminate for any input: should it also not terminate, or should it terminate for at least one input (because you consider $\bot$ to be one of the “outputs” of $P$)? Your problem is not stated precisely. Depending on the statement you meant, this may be possible (like in Raphael's interpretation) or trivial ($alter(P)(x) = P(x)+1$).

Comment: @Gilles In the context of computabiloty, we typically assume that "undefined" aka "loop" aka "does not halt" is a value in such formulae, i.e. halting with any result is "$\neq$" not halting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea fails (assuming all `P` are allowed), and that's not by accident.

1. You can not find an input for with `P` halts in finite time.
   `P` may *never* halt, in which case that line in your program loops;
   thus, the program behaves exactly the same as `P`.
2. You can skip finding `k` and do

   ```
   alter(P, x) =
     P(x) + 1
   ```

   This is the same idea as you have (note how it alters the semantics on
    *all* inputs on which `P` halts) but does not require us to find
    an input on which `P` halts.

   However, it's still fails for the never-halting program -- but, at least,
    only that one!
3. What if we just output `1` or any other value sometimes?
    That takes care of never-halting `P`, but for each such
    hack with a static, computable "abort and output `c`"-criterion
    -- that includes runtime bounds! -- we can build easy counterexamples.
    Idea: `if ( criterion ) then c else something`.

So that looks bad; we can't compute uncomputable criteria! And we have to "decide"
after finite time for any fixed `x` (otherwise the never-halting `P` skrews us).

When prospects are this bleak, it's sometimes wise to try the other direction.
What if the problem *can not* be solved, that is `alter` does not exist?
In fact, given sufficient background in computability, it is clear that such
a function can not exist.

Assume any computable, total function $\mathtt{alter} : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.
We understand natural numbers as (the numbers of) programs in some
Turing-complete programming language $\phi$.
More specifically, let $\phi$ be a [suitable numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering) of all (partially) computable functions; 
we then denote by $\phi_i$ the function computed by program $i$.

Now, by [Kleene's recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem)
there is some index (program) $i^*$ so that $\varphi_{i^*} = \varphi_{\mathtt{alter}(i^*)}$, 
that is $\mathtt{alter}$ *has no effect* on $i^*$, semantically. 
Stronger versions show that there are *infinitely many* such $i^*$ so there's no hope fixing this.

In summary, no such program `alter` that works on all input programs can exist.

If you allow only `P` that halt for at least some `x`, your approach works; the proof is elementary (show that `alter` is computable, and that `alter(P)(k) != P(k)` for some `k`).